# No se lanza el evento change en select bootstrap en chrome

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap

Mi problema es el siguiente y es que este código:

```
$("#consultas").change(function(){
    console.log("opcion2");
    alert("Hola");
});
```

Funciona correctamente en `Firefox` pero no sé porque no en `Chrome` (En otros navegadores no he probado). Es un evento que quiero lanzar en un `select` con clases de `Bootstrap`, o sea está en un proyecto usando `jQuery` y `Bootstrap`.

He probado soluciones que dan en la web como:

```
$('#consultas').on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
  var selected = $(e.currentTarget).val();
});
```

Lo raro es que funcione en un navegador y en otro no.

Comment: Por favor, añade tu codigo HTML. Me enfrente varias veces a este error y en la mayoria de los casos se trataba de un ID duplicado, algunos navegadores en estos casos utilizan el primer elemento con dicho ID q aparezca en el DOM, otros simplemente ignoran la ejecucion. Intenta usar una clase unica o cambiar el ID para depurar el codigo.

Comment: ¿Puedes enseñar también el código html relacionado? Puede ser que dupliques id's como te indica @MaxDominguez

Comment: ¿Acaso estas usando algún `plugin` para crear el `select`? Por ejemplo, [`Bootstrap Select`](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/). Te pregunto esto por el evento `changed.bs.select` que intentas usar.

Comment: El código html es bastante extenso pero lo pondré si no me queda más remedio. Os he hecho caso y he depurado el código cambiando el ID y sigue sin funcionar. Si, estoy utilizando el plugin select2 pero sólo los estilos ya que no veo ningún script relacionado. Pero es que tampoco funciona el evento click

Comment: Solucionado: Perdón pero era sólo borrar la caché del navegador. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En [`Select2 programatic control`](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic-control) utilizan en cambio de `DOM`

Ejemplo usando ***`select2:select`***

```js
$('.Select2').select2().on("select2:select", function (e) {
  console.log('Cambio')
  console.log(e.params.data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="Select2" style="width: 100px;">
  <option>&nbsp;</option>
  <option>uno</option>
  <option>dos</option>
  <option>tres</option>
</select>
```

Ejemplo usando ***`change`***

```js
$('.Select2').select2().on("change", function (e) {
  console.log('Cambio')
  console.log(e.params)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="Select2" style="width: 100px;">
  <option>&nbsp;</option>
  <option>uno</option>
  <option>dos</option>
  <option>tres</option>
</select>
```

No hay diferencia en la forma de cambio pero si lo que ocupas es capturar `id`, `clase`, etc. del elemento seleccionado es mejor usar `select2:select`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar conn ésto si onchange no te funciona

```js
document.getElementById('consultas').addEventListener('change', function() {
    alert('cambiado');
}, false);
```

```html
 <select id="consultas">
  <option>uno</option>
  <option>dos</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: ¿Como te funciona si estas dando evento de change a el formulario?¿Y si no tienes un formulario?

Comment: presiona en test aqui abajo y veras que funciona. Puedes ponerle al select tambien. Solo le pude al form porque asi lo tenía en mi código. En síntesis el script que puse proba no le hagas caso al html. Pone el id de tu código y verás que fija funciona

Comment: Listo actualizado sin el form